# How to navigate to a new route in test

Tags: angular

I'm testing an angular component (navbar) that displays different information depending on the route, with some menu buttons hidden. So I need to change the route before running the test. I thought this would be easy (and it probably is) but can't figure out how that's done. All the search results relate to testing the routing module its self.

**navbar.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('Navbar Component', () => {
  let router: Router;
  // Other definitions...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // Configuring Testbed etc...
  }))

  describe('routes A', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
      router = TestBed.get(Router)
      router.navigate(['/', 'a']);
    }))

    it('should show the relevant links', async(() => {
      // Testing code
    }))
  })
})
```

The code above gives me the error `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'a'`. How can I change the route in the tests?

In the component, the changes I want to test look like this:

**navbar.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit () {
  this.router.events
  .subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      // Do stuff
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to emit events on the router for testing is with the `RouterTestingModule` rather than mocking the router. It should be imported from `@angular/router/testing`

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
```

Add it to the imports when configuring the `TestBed`

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ myComponent ],
    imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
    providers: []
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

Now you can emit events on the router during the tests:

```
it('sets logged in to true if the url includes \'login\'', () => {
  const router = TestBed.get(Router);
  router.events.next(new NavigationStart(1, '/a'));

  // expect...
});
```

Note that I haven't cast the router to type Router. This will prevent you from calling next on the `router.events` because the router events are an observable.

Answer (score 0):

in angular you can use routerLink to navigate between routes in **app-routing.module.ts** You can use it like that : `<h1>routerLink="/search"</h1>`

And if you want to change the path of routes you can go on your **app-routing.module.ts**.
I hope this will be help you !

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but my question is specifically about how to change the route in the tests rather than in the main application.

Comment: Oh yeah okey, sorry i didn't understand that ! I don't have exemple to show you that sorry, good luck, and i would be interest if you find a solution !